# h:commandLink in p:autocomplete not passing querystring parameters correctly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm trying to perform an action through a command link in a autocomplete component (Primefaces)

I have the same structure in others parts of the code, and it works, so I don't understand why in this case it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{secondaryModel['mainBean'] == null}" styleClass="selector-title">
    <label>#{msgs['attendee.view.contact.search']}</label>
    <p:autoComplete id="autocomplete-contact" value="#{secondaryModel['searchBean']}" completeMethod="#{autocompleteAction.completeContacts}" 
        var="contact" itemValue="#{contact}" itemLabel="#{contact.fullName}"
        converter="#{secondaryModel['autocompleteBeanConverter']}"
        minQueryLength="3" maxResults="20" styleClass="autocomplete" widgetVar="autocompleteContactWidget"
        onfocus="triggerAutoComplete(autocompleteContactWidget, this.value)" onblur="blurAutoComplete(autocompleteContactWidget)">
        <f:attribute name="excludeRelatedContacts" value="#{false}" />
        <p:column>
            #{contact.fullName}
            <h:commandLink action="loadContact" styleClass="hide" >
                <f:param name="param" value="#{paramEncryptionHelper.encryptParameters('contactToAssignId', contact.contactId)}" />
                <f:ajax execute="@form" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:autoComplete>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is the webflow:

```
<transition on="loadContact">
        <evaluate expression="contactAction.loadContact(secondaryModel, requestParameters.contactToAssignId, messageContext)" />

        <render fragments="modal-panels, history, notification" />
    </transition>
```

Then I pass the contact to another component, but it is null!

I debugged with Chrome to see if the param I'm trying to pass to the webflow is triggered, and it is. It seems that the action is not performed, in fact if I try to debug the Java code it doesn't go to the method.

The logs:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/UNCDB] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'contacts' of flow 'int/contact'] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/pages/int/contact/contact.xhtml @31,72 value="#{contact.lastName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'contact' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1034)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:964)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1237)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:702)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1652)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:362)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:121)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:120)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:226)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.jemmic.authperform.common.front.filter.ParamEncryptionFilter.doFilter(ParamEncryptionFilter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.jemmic.authperform.common.front.filter.AjaxSessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(AjaxSessionTimeoutFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" />
```

I changed it to `<f:ajax />`. This is because the `execute="@form"` attribute causes parameters to not be included in the query string.